# Lifetime scope of the below transient class in autofac

Tags: c#, scope, autofac

I just started learning autofac and I am not sure about the lifetime scope of the below transient class.

`builder.Register<MySampleClass>().As<IMySampleClass>();`

Is a new instance created each time it is resolved or is it created once per thread or is it created and scoped when a new Task is created?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, a new instance will be created each time your application calls `Resolve` in the same lifetime scope.

You have other possibilities and I suggest you take a look at the [official documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html).